# Keep sending multiple requests when use react-gtm-module library in sepecic route in Next.js

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

As title, i use react-gtm-module library in Next.js.
And there is a route as http://localhost:3000/dynamic/%5Bid%5D
And this route imports the component like below:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module';

useEffect(() => {
  TagManager.initialize({ gtmId: 'GTM-xxxxxx' });
});

const Dynamic = () => {
...
}
export default Dynamic;
```

It turns out that TagManager indeed send request to `googletagmanager.com` and other requests including `m.vpadn.com` etc. But it keeps sending multiple requests like `https://www.google-analytics.com` and others as picture.

[image]

It will make this route of website loading continuously. But there are problems in other routes like http://localhost:3000/blog/%5Bid%5D, it only shows problem in http://localhost:3000/dynamic/%5Bid%5D.

I have tried add script manually to send request. It does not work.
I have tried to change name as http://localhost:3000/dynamic-test/%5Bid%5D, It works, it will not keep sending multiple requests. But it is difficult to change the route name.

My expecting is to send once gtm request and not change the route name.